# How to assign a custom style to a list view filter in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, filter, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a list view with a filter , How can i change the filter theme , add specific style to it by css ? since i need to modify the filter icon , border but i don't know how to  assign these styles to it ,  Please help me ..

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">

<div  data-role="header" data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false" data- fullscreen="false"   data-theme="b">

<div  style="padding-top:15px;" > <font  color="white"   size="6px" >Index </font></div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"  >

<ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..  " 
data-split-icon="delete"  style="margin-top: 30px;" > 
    <li> element1</li>
     <li> element2</li>
     <li> element3</li>
     <li> element4</li>
     <li> element5</li>
     <li> element6</li>

    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *search input* and assign an *id*.

```
<input type="search" id="custom-filter" />
```

In `ul`, add `data-input` attribute with value the *id* of the *search input* starting with `#` hash tag `data-input="#custom-filter"`.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#custom-filter">
```

Create a custom style and add it to `#custom-filter` *div* to have the styles applied on the input.

```
$("#custom-filter").closest("div").addClass("styles");
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yCLqU/)

Comment: @OmarThanksI have tried it but it didn't work in my app as jsfiddle the border is applied to the page( around the page) and the placeholder didn't appear in the filter!

Comment: @user I have used different id in fiddle than in the answer. Place holder should be added to the custom input.

Comment: @OmarIhave used the code that in the jsfiddle  , and i have insured that the input id , and  data-input in the listview are the same in my code

Comment: @OmarRegarding Placeholder, you assign it in  the listview as appear in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yCLqU/

Comment: @OmarI used this code in my jQuery mobile 1.4.0 app the problem is that the border appears around the page not around the search input  can you help me please?? I have tried many times to make it work but the border still appears around the page

Comment: @OmarThe problem is in the closest("div") it will be the page content because  this  the border appeared around the page , and when i tried this <div><input type="search" id="custom-filter" /></div> the result appeared as the image that i uploaded above , can you help me in solving this problem please?

Comment: @user replace `closest("div")` with `closest("ui-input-search")`

Comment: @OmarI tried it didn't work , the border didn't appear at all

Comment: then you're calling `$("#custom-filter").closest("div").addClass("styles");` before the `input` is created. Where have you placed that code? @user

Comment: this is what I have  tried:                                                   document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);  function onDeviceReady()
{$('#custom-filter').closest("ui-input-search").addClass("styles");}

Comment: @user you have to place it inside `pagecreate`. on `deviceready` the page isn't created yet so the style goes to closest div.

Comment: @OmarI tried it ,but unfortunately  the problem still :( the border didn't appear , what can we do now ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46258/discussion-between-omar-and-user)